# Can't install pycrypto under python3 (using pip3) but it is installed under python[2] in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, package, python-2.x

I have both Python 2 and 3 installed in parallel on Ubuntu 18.04.1:

```python
#uname -a
Linux mysvr-1 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#python --version
Python 2.7.17

#python3 --version 
Python 3.8.8
```

I am trying to run a script written for Python2 (and which uses simple-crypt which calls pycrypto) using python3 but I cannot install simple-crypt under python3 (pip3) because pycrypto install fails, even though they are both installed fine under python2.

I see the follow errors during install:

```python
#python3 -m pip install simple-crypt
Collecting simple-crypt
  Using cached simple-crypt-4.1.7.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: simple-crypt, pycrypto
  Building wheel for simple-crypt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for simple-crypt: filename=simple_crypt-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl size=8933 sha256=35465628dbc2d4671aef879ccd6d24d09e01ca11afa173fd8d62c5cbcfb8e05b
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/7f/0b/04/30775cf18395f400fba1112955512e434a896bc5f0592eaf82
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-31add99g
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/
  Complete output (215 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/Crypto
  copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/Crypto
  ...
  <...many other lines of copying and creating...>
  ...
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  running build_configure
  checking for gcc... gcc
  checking whether the C compiler works... yes
  ...
  <...many other successful checks...>
  ...
  checking for memset... yes
  configure: creating ./config.status
  config.status: creating src/config.h
  warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
  building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -fwrapv -Wall -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/MD2.o
  src/MD2.c:31:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Successfully built simple-crypt
Failed to build pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, simple-crypt
    Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zy55j0yw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/pycrypto
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/
    Complete output (160 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    ...
    <...many other lines of copying and creating...>
    ...
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    running build_configure
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -fwrapv -Wall -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/MD2.o
    src/MD2.c:31:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wo7npi4x/pycrypto_1a5c9f1c1c3446a6a44b1061e80eedc8/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zy55j0yw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/pycrypto Check the logs for full command output.

#
```

I thinking it is probably down to this:

```
src/MD2.c:31:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Questions I have are:

1. Can I download the package and install from local tar?
2. Can I install to Python3 from the existing Python2 installation?
3. Can I tell Python3 how to 'use' packages currently installed under (and usable by) Python2?

Any thoughts/advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer - to Question 1 above:

> 1. Can I download the package and install from local tar?

### Install Python Module Manually:

```python
# Verify the module is not already installed
python3 -m pip list
# As above - Python 2.x
python -m pip list

# Download the module
curl <MODULE_DOWNLOAD_URL> -o <MODULE_FILE_NAME>

# Make sure setuptools are up to date - Python 3.x
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
# As above - Python 2.x
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools

# Extract the downloaded gzipped tar file if necessary
tar -xvf <MODULE_FILE_NAME>
# cd into the extracted module folder if created
cd <MODULE_FOLDER>

# Run the included setup.py script to install the module
python3 setup.py install
# Same for Python 2.x
python setup.py install

# Verify the module was successfully installed
python3 -m pip list
# As above - Python 2.x
python -m pip list
```

If all went well, the new module should now appear in the list of installed/available modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try pip install pipwin and then pipwin install pycrypto but if this doesn't work it means you might have to downgrade your python version to 3.3 and 1.5.2 is not supported since.this is so because pycrypto was launched in 2013 when python 3.8 wasn't made so there is no support.

Comment: Thanks. pipwin is for Windows - this is on Ubuntu.